# GWT, RichTextArea,  set selected text size in pixels

Tags: gwt, font-size, pixel, rich-text-editor

There is a function that sets size of the selected text: **RichTextArea.BasicFormatter.setFontSize(RichTextArea.FontSize fontSize))**

It takes an absolute font size argument (1-7). But I need to set size in pixels. Is it possible to do somehow?

Any suggestions or ideas are welcomed =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to implement your own control (i.e. a ListBox) which on selection would insert tags like

```
<span style="font-size: 12px;"> ... </span>
```

around the selected text.

A good implementation will also remove unnecessary tags if a user applies font sizes to overlapping portions of the text.

You can add this control to the toolbar that you use with your RichTextArea.

Comment: well, I've thought nearly like this.
just there are some difficulties with overlapping selection (e.g. first part of the selection is bold and another one is italic) so I hoped to find out more easy way.